# Looping through a list in Python does not return the expected True or False value

Tags: python, list

I am creating a Bingo console application in Python and am having a problem with (possibly) the `remaining_selections()` function.

The idea is when a user guesses a number in the list, that number gets replaced with an 'X' (single digit) or 'XX' (double digit).

After each user input, the list is checked to see if any there are any integers remaining in the list and if not the user has a BINGO.

The problem I'm facing is that the return value of the `remaining_selections()` function always returns `True` regardless of the logic I use.

The reason I suspect the problem is in the `remaining_selections()` function is because when I hard code a `False` value the code executes a 'Bingo!!'

Any ideas where I am going wrong??

It's not a large program so have included the entire code.

```
def draw_bingo_card():
    '''
    Draw bingo card from bingo_card list
    '''

    print(
        f"\n",
        f"----------------\n",
        f"   BINGO CARD\n",
        f"----------------\n",
        f"| {bingo_card[0]}|{bingo_card[1]}|{bingo_card[2]}|{bingo_card[3]}|{bingo_card[4]}|\n",
        f"----------------\n",
        f"|{bingo_card[5]}|{bingo_card[6]}|{bingo_card[7]}|{bingo_card[8]}|{bingo_card[9]}|\n",
        f"----------------\n",
        f"\n",
    )


def remove_number(number):
    '''
    Check if the number chosen matches a number in the list
    If a number matches, change the value to an X
    ''' 
    for i, item in enumerate(bingo_card):
        if item == number:
            if number < 10:
                bingo_card[i] = "X"
            else:
                bingo_card[i] = "XX"


def remaining_selections():
    '''
    Check the bingo_card list and if any values 
    are not X or XX return True (indicating that 
    there are remaining selections)
    '''
    integers_exist = False

    for item in bingo_card:
        if item != "X" or item != "XX": 
            integers_exist = True
    return integers_exist




# Bingo Card List
bingo_card = [7,26,40,58,73,14,22,34,55,68]

# Draw Bingo Card to Terminal
draw_bingo_card()


while True:
    try:
        user_input = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 80 inclusive: "))

        #####################
        # DEBUGING STATEMENT
        if user_input == 0:
            print(bingo_card)
        #####################

        # Check to see if user has entered a valid integer range
        if user_input < 1 or user_input > 80:
            print("ERROR: Numbers betwen 1 and 80 are only valid")
            continue
        else:
            remove_number(user_input)
            draw_bingo_card()

            if remaining_selections():
                continue
            else:
                print(
                    "\n",
                    "***********\n",
                    "* BINGO!! *\n",
                    "***********\n"
                )
                break

    except:
        # User has entered an invalid selection
        print("ERROR: Invalid selection.  Please choose an INTEGER VALUE between 1 and 80 inclusive")
        continue
```

Comment: Hint: A value cannot be equal to `"X"` and `"XX"` at the same time.

Comment: I realise now that changing `or` to `and` fixes this issue.  But I cannot figure out why?  
I thought that having `and` in there would have required both values to be `True`?
Are you able to shed some light into what is going on here?

Comment: @Samwise explained it very clearly in their comments to the answer, but I suggest you to read about [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remaining_selections():
    '''
    Check the bingo_card list and if any values 
    are not X or XX return True (indicating that 
    there are remaining selections)
    '''
    integers_exist = False

    for item in bingo_card:
        if item != "X" and item != "XX":  # it should be `and` instead of `or`
            integers_exist = True
    return integers_exist
```

you could simplify it even more with:

```
if item not in ["X", "XX"]:
    ...
```

Comment: Although this did fix my issue, I cannot understand why?
My understanding (which is obviously wrong) is that: when using `or` any value that is `True` will return `True` even if the other value was `False`?  Whereas, using `and` both values would have to be `True` to return `True`?

Comment: Your understanding is correct -- what you're missing is that if `item` is `"X"` then `item != "XX"` will still be true.  It's not possible for **any** value of `item` to make that `or` statement false, which is why that function would always return `True`.

Comment: @minlopalis That's logic! `not('X' or 'XX')` is equivalent to `not('X') and not('XX')`. It is like multiplying a bracketed term with `-1`, where it flips the signs in the term.

Comment: Maybe the missing piece is that `item != "X" or item != "XX"` translates to English as "if item is not X or item is not XX", which is **not the same** as "if item is neither X nor XX".